# Text align for mobile device

Tags: jquery, css, listview, mobile

I'm having some problmes with css and i dont really understand why.I need help for mobile view

This is the website : https://digitalicus.com/ If you have time to check is much easier to understood why my issue is. The list is not centered and also the textes from product description

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/zYEmC.jpg)

Vla

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a media query for mobile and remove the float from your 'li' in your list tag and the add text align center. Assuming you want the list to remain in a row for tablet and desktop.

You could also try using [Flex-Box](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) for your list items.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the offset class from the container and apply the col-xs-offset-1 class to the column.

---> You have

[image]

--> How it should be

[image]